# Ember template not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have my rails api to serve the list of tasks as json to the url

> localhost.domain.com/tasks

I had defined the routes in ember as

```
router.js
this.route('tasks',function() {
    this.route('index', {path: ''});
}
```

I have a template for "localhost.domain.com/tasks"

When i hit the route, its not rendering the template, instead the server response JSON is loaded

**Is there any restriction like , the server and ember routes must be different ? If not, how to overcome this ?**

Comment: Are you using ember-data ?. How do you request to get the data ?.. try consider `ember serve --proxy http://localhost.domain.com/ ` to proxy request or change in application adapter host property

Comment: You have to put `path: '/'` there. The routes of your Ember app aren't related to your server's app. What's happening is that you're going to your APIs server, so you're seeing the JSON response. How are you running ember?

Comment: You should really use the port you are using for your Ember app. You don't complain about inability to run Ember app so i assume you are able to run it. If you run your ember app in development using `ember s` and it allows you to do so this means the port it uses is not taken by any other service. You would just have to use that port for your app in the browser. Like - `127.0.0.1:4200/tasks`. Of course all this is true only if you are not running a build on remote server with separate web-server app to serve your `index.html`

Comment: `Path:'/'` didnt work for me. I also tried ember serve option. To be specific, i mapped my localhost.domain.com with `nginx server` so the url actually requests is `127.0.0.1:4200/tasks` to the rails api